# Open a terminal with font size option through command line

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I need a command line to open a gnome-terminal in a specified position of my screen and with specified font-size.

I'm already able to open it into specified position using `--geometry` option; but then I need to manually press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> four times to obtain needed look.

Noting that I don't want this font-size to be a default option for all my terminals, is there a way to open it with (very) small font from command line?

Comment: Have you tried creating a profile with the desired font size, then starting the terminal with `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME`?

Comment: @Jos thank you - I haven't. How do I create profile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open `gnome-terminal` and choose `File/New profile`. You will see the current defaults.
2. Enter a new profile name, let's say SmallFont. Modify the settings (including font size) as desired, and save.
3. Open a new window with `File/Open Terminal/SmallFont` to check if things look OK.
4. Close this window.
5. Enter `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SmallFont`. This should now have the proper font size.

Comment: Correct! It also works with --geometry option. Note that under Edit->Preferences menu you can edit and delete all stored profiles.

Answer (score 2):

To emulate the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> behavior you can pass `zoom` argument. For instance:

```
gnome-terminal --zoom=0.8
```